# UIPopoverViewController in ios7?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios7, uipopoverbackgroundview

In iOS 6 UIPopoverView have border with black translucent colour but iOS 7 do not have border because iOS 7 become transparent. how to add border with black translucent colour in iOS 7.

Can anyone know please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: please send screenshot for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popover in iOS7 is white and blur, from Apple:

> In iOS 7, the popover background is a white blur, which means that the
>   background of the popover’s content view can be transparent. A table
>   view inside a popover automatically uses a translucent appearance;
>   custom content inside a popover should use a translucent appearance.

Unfortunately Popover is not customizable, you need to use some alternative:

[GIKPopoverBackgroundView](https://github.com/GiK/GIKPopoverBackgroundView)

[WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController)

Or any other ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UIPopoverBackgroundView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html) to achieve a custom but similar effect.

There are [tutorials](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-customizing-popovers/) and [libraries](https://github.com/GiK/GIKPopoverBackgroundView) readily available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this for ios7.0 and later?

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
popoverController.contentViewController.view.layer.borderWidth = 5;
popoverController.contentViewController.view.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```